# Perl Windows alternatives for "system" ( opening multiple processes )

Tags: windows, perl, multiprocessing, system

So long story short, I'm trying to run a linux perl script in Windows ( with few modifications ).

On Unix it works just fine, but on Windows I come to the conclusion that calling for system doesn't work the same as on Unix and so it doesn't create multiple processes.

Below is the code :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
open (FIN, 'words.txt'); while (<FIN>) {
   chomp;
   my $line = $_;
   system( "perl script.pl $line &" );
   
}
close (FIN);
```

So basically, I have 5 different words in "words.txt" which I want each and every one to be used one by one when calling for script.pl , which means :

```
word1 script.pl
word2 script.pl
word3 script.pl
etc
```

As of now it opens just the first word in words.txt and it loops with that one only. As I said, on Unix it works perfectly, but not on Windows.

I've tried to use "start" *system( "start perl script.pl $line &" );* and it works...except it opens 5 additional CMDs to do the work. I want it to do the work on the same window.

If anyone has any idea how this can work on window, i'll really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Has nothing to do with `system`. You're passing a `sh` shell command to `cmd`. The `cmd` equivalent to `&` is achieved using `start`. Though here, `system(1, "perl script.pl $line")` would do (code injection bug aside)

Comment: Hm! I think this works. For a moment it showed the output on the cmd windows fine, but now everytime i run it, it opens the processes in the background but on the cmd window it shows nothing. I assume it .. work silently which is good. Any way to show the output on the window? For testing purpose, I want to see it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually it acts weird. It doesn't loop well and it starts after I press like .. 2-3 "enters" ? I assume it's a "go" when I press enter, which is .. not ideal! Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Looking at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start), `system("start /b perl ...")` might work without opening new consoles too.

Answer (score 2):

According to [perlport](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlport#system) :

> **system**
>
> (Win32) [...] `system(1, @args)` spawns an external process and
> immediately returns its process designator, without waiting for it to
> terminate. Return value may be used subsequently in `wait` or `waitpid`.
> Failure to `spawn()` a subprocess is indicated by setting `$?` to 255 <<
> 8. `$?` is set in a way compatible with Unix (i.e. the exit status of the subprocess is obtained by `$? >> 8`, as described in the
> documentation).

I tried this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
say "Starting..";
my @pids;
for my $word (qw(word1 word2 word3 word3 word5)) {
    my $pid = system(1, "perl script.pl $word" );
    if ($? == -1) {
        say "failed to execute: $!";
    }
    push @pids, $pid; 
}

#wait for all children to finish
for my $pid (@pids) {
    say "Waiting for child $pid ..";
    my $ret = waitpid $pid, 0;
    if ($ret == -1) {
        say " No such child $pid";
    }
    if ($? & 127) {
        printf " child $pid died with signal %d\n", $? & 127;
    }
    else {
        printf " child $pid exited with value %d\n", $? >> 8;
    }
}
say "Done.";
```

With the following child script `script.pl` :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
say "Starting: $$";
sleep 2+int(rand 5);
say "Done: $$";
sleep 1;
exit int(rand 10);
```

I get the following output:

```
Starting..
Waiting for child 7480 ..
Starting: 9720
Starting: 10720
Starting: 9272
Starting: 13608
Starting: 13024
Done: 13608
Done: 10720
Done: 9272
Done: 9720
Done: 13024
 child 7480 exited with value 9
Waiting for child 13344 ..
 child 13344 exited with value 5
Waiting for child 17396 ..
 child 17396 exited with value 3
Waiting for child 17036 ..
 child 17036 exited with value 6
Waiting for child 17532 ..
 child 17532 exited with value 8
Done.
```

Seems to work fine..

Comment: `$?` isn't meaningful until a background finishes and is reaped with `waitpid`. Checking `$?` immediately after the `system 1,...` call will just tell you whether the background spawning was successful.

Comment: This works great, except I really want to open the words.txt file and also do the chomp since the word lines are like "word hi there", "word2 how are you" , etc and I want to .. grab the whole line.

Comment: I think i've make it work with the above code and also make it open my word.txt file. Will update soon!

Comment: @mob Thanks for clarifying. I have updated my answer

Comment: Ok, this works great ``` my @pids;
open (FIN, 'words.txt'); while (<FIN>) {
 chomp;
   my $line = $_;
    my $pid = system(1, "perl script.pl $line" ); ``` Now, what I do with my CPU? :) As it goes between 80-100% A limit I assume?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Win32::Process`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::Process) to get finer control over creating a new process than `system` gives you on Windows. In particular, the following doesn't create a new console for each process like using `system("start ...")` does:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;
# Older versions don't work with an undef appname argument.
# Use the full path to perl.exe on them if you can't upgrade
use Win32::Process 0.17; 

my @lines = qw/foo bar baz quux/; # For example instead of using a file
my @procs;
for my $line (@lines) {
    my $proc;
    if (!Win32::Process::Create($proc, undef, "perl script.pl $line", 1,
                                NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, ".")) {
        $_->Kill(1) for @procs;
        die "Unable to create process: $!\n";
    }
    push @procs, $proc;
}

$_->Wait(INFINITE) for @procs;
# Or
# use Win32::IPC qw/wait_all/;
# wait_all(@procs);
```

---

As Yet Another Way To Do It, [the `start` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) takes a `/b` option to not open a new command prompt.

```perl
system("start /b perl script.pl $line");
```

Comment: If you're using Strawberry Perl, the version of `Win32::Process` bundled with it is buggy; need to upgrade with `cpanm Win32::Process` for the above to work.

Comment: Ok. I've tried it and your code also works great! Much like the one from below. On both i've added to open the words as in words.txt, and it works flawless...with a problem that my CPU is going high-sky, but that's something I think i can manage to .. lower it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes! I'm using the Strawberry Perl and I installed the Win32::Process through cpan just fine. Also, the system("start /b perl script.pl $line"); doesn't seems to work. I mean it says "Starting xxx" but nothing is shown. The processes are opened in the background but they just.."hang" there. I wonder why ..

Comment: @Sandok A lot depends on what the child processes actually do. My test case just prints it's arguments on standard output and sleeps for a few seconds. (Oh, [`Proc::Background`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Proc::Background) is a cross platform alternative I just learned of that might be worth looking into)