# simultaneously need to exit current perl script while opening the pdf file

Tags: perl

I have a script to open the pdf file (Not in Adobe Acrobat application) instead Sumatra application (Pdf viewer).

```
system("start Sumatra C:/Users/test/Desktop/19June.pdf");
exit;
```

The problem is once we need to close the pdf file then only the script exited. But the requirement is the tool will be exit and not considered the opened pdf file.

Comment: Play around with [Win32::Process](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::Process)?

Comment: See also [Perl Windows alternatives for "system" ( opening multiple processes )](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69682218/2173773)

Comment: @Shawn I couldn't use Win32::Process in linux might be ??

Comment: You have a file path like that and you're using Linux?

Comment: @Shawn In question I have mentioned windows path exactly... however I need to integrate in linux also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `exec` instead of `system`. `exec` replaces the current process with the one given, while `system` will start a new process and wait for it to exit.

Comment: Re "*`exec` replaces the current process with the one given*", No, not on Windows.    ...But it is emulated by spawning and exiting, so the solution does work.